# Praying with a bad breath on Tisha Bav?

Tags: tisha-bav

I’m pretty sure that on a non fast day, one must wash their mouth before praying, to avoid saying the name of Hashem with a bad breath. So if your not allowed to brush your teeth on a fast day (I believe), then is it permissible to pray with a bad breath on fast days?

Comment: Why don't you ask to verify if what you're "pretty sure" about is true before asking if it applies on Tisha Bav?

Comment: It's not mandatory that one wash his mouth before uttering God's name (or praying), cf. Shulchan Aruch 4:17, though it is prohibited to consume liquid on a fast-day. Hence we don't wash/rinse the mouth lest one ingest the water. In short: a good habit doesn't outweigh a prohibition. (OTOH, brushing/rinsing the mouth with the head faced down, taking precautions not to swallow, some would permit on a fast-day.)